# Graph Theory: How quickly will triadic closure create a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine we are given a graph $G$ comprised of nodes $N$ and edges $E$.  Assume the graph is connected (i.e. there exists a path connecting any pair of nodes).  We can then iteratively update this graph by adding new links in accordance with triadic closure.  Specifically, at each step:

for any triplet of nodes $\{i, j, k\} \in N$ such that $(i,j) \in E$ and $(j,k) \in E$ but $(i,k) \notin E$, we add the edge $(i,k)$ to $E$.  (In other words, if two of the three edges in the triangle are present, we add the missing edge.)

My question is, how many steps will be needed before the graph is complete (i.e. every pair of nodes is connected by an edge)?

I conjecture that the answer is the graph width minus 1.  (By graph width I mean the number of edges between the two most distant nodes in the original graph, where distance is measured measured by minimum path length.)  From playing with a few examples of small size, this seems to hold but I cannot prove it in general.

Comment: What do you mean by "step"?  Surely each triadic closure just adds one edge, so the number of triadic closures is simply $p(p-1)/2 - q$, where $p=|N|$ and $q=|E|$?

Comment: @DrXorile I took the operation to mean that a single step involved the identification of all such $\{i, j, k\}$ triples in the graph and the addition all the resulting $ik$ edges simultaneously. For example, the star becomes a complete graph in one step, since any two vertices are connected by a path of length at most two.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ and $v$ be nonadjacent vertices in a connected graph $G$. Since $G$ is connected, there is a path $u$, $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$, $v$. Since $u \sim x_1$ and $x_1 \sim x_2$, we have the edge $ux_2$ after one triadic closure. (Perhaps we already had the edge $ux_2$, but that only makes the convergence quicker.) Now we have $u \sim x_2$ and $x_2 \sim x_3$, so we have the edge $ux_3$ after a second triadic closure. Continuing in this way, we have the edge $uv$ after $n$ triadic closures, which is one less than the graph width at most.

This bound is best possible, since a path on $n$ edges will require exactly $n-1$ triadic closures.