# Transform connected graph to complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

This question is related to friendship represented by graphs.

Asssuming G is a connected graph in which a node is someone and a vertex is a friendship. So two connected nodes equals two friends.

If we say that for each iteration, all my friend's friends become my friends, how many iteration will I need before the connected graph becomes complete ?

I think that for a path we will have E-1 iterations (where E=number of edges), while for a cycle it's obviously less but I can't quite put the math behind it.

Is there a generality, if so, how do I find it ?

Comment: What you are looking for is the diameter of the graph.

Comment: @5xum If i have a path of three nodes A-B-C (A and C not connected), the diameter is 2 and it takes one iteration to link A-C since A is linked to B and B to C. So, the answer is diameter minus one ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

You can read abour graph diameter here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory).

Generally there is no simpler answer to your question than that - number of iterations needed equals to $d(G)$-1 where $G$ is your graph.

If you want to know how to compute it algorithmically you can see some discussion on that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646307/algorithm-for-diameter-of-graph

A somewhat more interesting question would be: what if with each iteration the same thing happen to everyone - for any person $A$ friends of $A$'s friends also become $A$'s friends. Obviously, the graph kind of "shrinks" with every iteration... I mean that the diameter is decreasing with every step, so that affects the answer.

For path graph $P_n$ with $n$ edges answer clearly is $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$.

Comment: By the way, here is another post about the same thing: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380702/graph-theory-how-quickly-will-triadic-closure-create-a-complete-graph?rq=1